# Prevent vue.js from re-rendering data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a Vue component which has a `prop` called `data`. This data prop receives the first 25 results from a backend query.

Ultimately we might want to fetch ~250 results and the rest of the results are being fetched with an AJAX call with an offset of 25.

This way the user can at least view the first 25 results straight away and we have a statically generated backend page with 25 results to ensure proper SEO.

The first 25 results are being set in a Vuex store and when the AJAX call has finished I want to merge my AJAX data of the remaining 225 results with the 25 results already there.

The problem that I am facing that when I am rendering out the results with a `v-for` the entire list re-renders when I merge the data, even though the first 25 results remain in order and the end result looks the same.

Is there any way to prevent this re-render from happening when I merge my data?

**Edit**

I used lodash `merge` to try and merge my values with seems to do something entirely different than simply using `concat` which works for my case.

In the case of a concat there seems to be no re-render.

Comment: So, what is the question now? Can you provide some code? Why don't you use `arr.push(...newElements)` ? Concat returns a **new** Array.

Comment: Also try using `:key="item.id"` with the `v-for` so that vue may recognize that the new array contains objects from the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using unshift and push to prepend and append when needed:

```
const offSet = state.currentPage * state.itemsPerPage;

const start = payload.slice(0, offSet - state.itemsPerPage);
const end = payload.slice(offSet);

rootState.filters.data.unshift(...start);
rootState.filters.data.push(...end);
```

This leaves the array intact and it works with pagination. This way no re-render is being done by Vue.js